# Programmatic creation of elements using Angular in the context of templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angular.js for the following project. Using a template document, the
application renders paragraphs using user-input in a fill-in-the-blanks style.
So there are fields that the user must fill, let’s call them Blanks. Those
fields, inside the paragraphs, are highlighted so the user knows they can
interact with them. They can be of type **date**, **email**, **text** or
**radio select**. When they are clicked, I want to display, next to the
paragraph, a little panel containing a description of or instructions on how to
fill the field followed by the form element.

I would like to use a readable format for the HTML templates so I can mix
regular text with Blanks. I was thinking of using attributes on div elements
to specify the description of the element and the placeholder or the default option.

Here is how I started :

```
<div class="chapter" title="Colours"> 
    <div class="article" title="Blue">
        Blue is a special colour because it gives me particular emotions. First
        of all, I feel
        <a href="" 
            class="blank"
            ng-click="selectQuestion()"
            doc-question="How does blue make you feel?"
            doc-type="text"
            doc-placeholder="like there is a wind in my ear."
            doc-data="colour.blue.feeling"
            >[[colour.blue.feeling]]</a>.
        Second of all, blue reminds me of
        <a href="" 
            class="blank"
            ng-click="selectQuestion()"
            doc-question="Pick the thing blue reminds you of"
            doc-placeholder="the sky".
            doc-choices="the sky, the sea, the ocean"
            doc-type="radio"
            doc-data="colour.blue.memory"
            >[[colour.blue.memory]]</a>
        like the first time I experienced the colour which was on
        <a href="" 
            class="blank"
            ng-click="selectQuestion()"
            doc-question="Select a day"
            doc-placeholder="01/01/2015"
            doc-type="date"
            doc-data="colour.blue.date"
            >[[colour.blue.date]]</a>.

    </div>
</div>
```

Then there would be a hidden, automatically generated form which binds the
input elements to the data inside the anchor elements with class 'blank' :

```
<form>
    <div>
        <h2>How does blue make you feel?</h2>
        <input type="text" ng-model="colour.blue.feeling">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Select a day</h2>
        <input type="text" ng-model="colour.blue.date">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Pick the thing blue reminds you off</h2>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="colour.blue.memory" name="colour.blue.memory" value="the sky"  >the sky<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="colour.blue.memory" name="colour.blue.memory" value="the sea"  checked>the sea<br>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="colour.blue.memory" name="colour.blue.memory" value="the ocean"> the ocean
    </div>
</form>
```

1. Does this problem have a name?
2. Is my approach reasonable?
3. How can I programmatically create the form and bind the fields to it (of
   course, I am not expecting code here, unless you can show me something similar).
4. To display only the part of the form that is of interest, with jQuery,
   I would hide all the divs in the form then detach the form and re-attach it to the
   div that is the Blank’s parent. Then I would show the div containing the relevant
   input(s) by selecting it using a distinctive attribute, invoke jQuery’s show()
   and it is done. How would I accomplish this using Angular?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How are users expected to enter their values?  If I understand correctly, they click the anchor tag and then enter the value?  If this was the case, why just have the `input`s right along side with the anchor tags but hidden - then clicking the anchor tags would toggle the visibility of the `input`.

Comment: You can to use a function to create the template (I think)